# Deleting Row Based on Cell Values

Tags: editor

I am attempting to create a additional menu option that allow me to automatically delete all rows that contain the text "Complete" in Column D.    The script I have runs and finishes with no errors but does not delete the rows.  I tried to find help on line and tweaked the code but same result

```
function readRows() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
  var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
  var values = rows.getValues();

  var rowsDeleted = 'Complete';
  for (var i = 'Complete'; i <= numRows - 1; i++) {
    var row = values[i];
    if (row[2] == 'Complete' || row[2] == '') {
      sheet.deleteRow((parseInt(i)+1) - rowsDeleted);
      rowsDeleted++;
    }
  }
};


function onOpen() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var entries = [{
    name : "Delete Rows where column shows Complete Text",
    functionName : "readRows"
  }];
  sheet.addMenu("Script Center Menu", entries);
};
```

Comment: Can you post the code please?

Comment: Ok done.  Im new to this so I definitely appreciate the assist.